# NPM & Node.js problem installing packages

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm

I've just installed Node.js, and I'm trying to install some packages now.

For example:

```
npm i -g @vue/cli
```

And here the output:

> Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near `'....1.tgz"},"engines":{"'`

Can someone help me? Who have the same issue?

Comment: please refer to Vue js official documentation for installation. and first-run `nmp i` command for installation whatever you missed package it will install automatically.
and `npm cache clean --force` you use these command for clear cache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Try to run these commands:

`npm cache clean --force`

And after that, try installing the module again

`npm i -g @vue/cli`